# Простая геоинформационная программа на java

Tags: java, графика, геолокация, геокодирование

Нужно написать простую программу по гео.системам в Intellij IDEA

Идея моей программы заключается в том, что у нас есть карта района,которая показывает нам локацию банков и курс валют в этом банке.

Какие средства для реализации программы нужно использовать?

1.Можно использовать графическую библиотеку или нужно что-то посерьезнее?

2.Как написать карту с банками и связать объекты с БД( нам нужно обновлять курсы валют)

Очень буду рада развернутым ответам, так как эта область для меня неизведанная.

Answer (score 1):

1. 1)Устанавливаете карту google в ваше приложение
   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/?hl=ru
2. Подключаетесь к сервису гугл
3. Посылаете асинхронный запрос на сервер. На сервере ваш код, допустим на php, делает запрос к БД достает оттуда курс валют и отправляет обратно (в виде JSON)в приложение.
4. Приложение переводит JSON  в массив и закрывает запрос.
5. т.к. банки у нас статичные то при загрузке карты ставите сразу метки по координатам на карту где находиться ваши банки и в информационном окне каждой метки, каждого банка пишите курс валюты, который находится у нас в массиве (шаг 4).
6. Ну и напоследок можете запустить таймер, который будет через n -  количество часов посылать запрос на сервер и обновлять карту.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать Google или Яндекс api.